# Python error 'int' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

Using the example below, `sklearn` with Python 3.5:

```
from sklearn import tree
features = [[140,1], [130,1], [150,0], [155,0]]
labels = [0,0,1,1]

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(features, labels)
print(clf.predict(155,0))
```

I get the error following error. I don't understand why I received this error, could someone explain?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ml.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(clf.predict(155,0))
  File "/Users/user/Documents/hello/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 404, in predict
    X = self._validate_X_predict(X, check_input)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/hello/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 371, in _validate_X_predict
    n_features = X.shape[1]
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the docs for [DecisionTreeClassifier.predict](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.predict), you can see you are passing the wrong data:

**predict(X, check_input=True)**

> Predict class or regression value for X.
>   For a classification model, the predicted class for each sample in X is returned. For a regression model, the predicted value based on X is returned.
>   Parameters:

```
X : array-like or sparse matrix of shape = [n_samples, n_features]
```

Comment: sorry, yes after reviewing it again I see that now. Thank you for your help.